# adjust the size of rendered component OtpInput in react bootstrap

Tags: grid, rendering, react-bootstrap, react-props, adjustment

here the verification code is not fitting in box.could someone suggest?
here is my code.

expecting that verification code fits in box col

here is my code:

```
 <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId='formBasicVerificationcode'>
                                                      <Form.Label>Enter verification code</Form.Label>
                                                      {/* <Form.Control
                                                        name="verificationcode"
                                                       
                                                       
                                                        required value={values.verificationcode}
                                                        onChange={handleChange} 
                                                        isInvalid={!!errors.verificationcode}
                                                      />
                                                     <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                                                        {errors.verificationcode}
                                                     </Form.Control.Feedback> */}
                                                        <OtpInput
                                                            inputStyle="inputStyle"
                                                            numInputs={numInputs}
                                                            isDisabled={isDisabled}
                                                            hasErrored={hasErrored}
                                                            errorStyle="error"
                                                            onChange={this.handleEmailOtpChange}
                                                            separator={<span>{separator}</span>}
                                                            isInputNum={false}
                                                            isInputSecure={isInputSecure}
                                                            value={emailotp}
                                                            placeholder={placeholder}
                                                            shouldAutoFocus
                                                        />
```

Comment: What is OtpInput? Some library or your own component? What do you mean by "not fitting"?

Comment: yes OtpInput is component in another file. the verification code ui box is going out and not fitting in the card the has password and submitt buttons , i need to align it properly

Comment: Can you then also provide the code for OtpInput component? Otherwise I can't help properly